# Largest set of different byte values unique when clearing bits

Tags: embedded, bit, data-representation

I am creating a data format, which will be stored in a DS2431 1-wire EEPROM. One page will be using EPROM emulation mode (where data once written can only be modified by clearing bits). In this page I want to store a byte with an ID, which cannot be changed to another valid value (due to only allowing clearing bits).

I am considering using the set of values that have a popcount of 4 (there are 70 different values). Clearing any bits means popcount is no longer 4, so this satisfies the desired property.

But could a set of byte values be found with more than 70 different values, that satisfy the property?

Comment: More of a math problem that either programming or embedded - you have narrowed the audience by tagging it thus - the application is largely irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @Clifford, Thank you for pointing that out. This was my first question on stackoverflow, so glad to get some advice on how to get the most relevant answer. However, I was struggling to describe the problem without describing the EPROM emulation, thus I ended up posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For an 8-bit value, using four bits is optimal.

If you have your 70 4-bit values and decide to add a 5-bit value as valid, you have to give up five 4-bit values that can be created by clearing a bit. Similarly, if you want a valid 3-bit value, you also have to give up five 4-bit values.

If you could increase the number of bits, then you can increase the ratio of possible values to bits used.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only 256 possible values and 8 possible populations it is a trivial task to test all possible population counts:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int popcount( uint8_t byte )
{
    int count = 0 ;
    for( uint8_t b = 0x01; b != 0; b <<= 1 )
    {
        count = count + (((byte & b) != 0) ? 1 : 0) ;
    }

    return count ;
}

int main()
{
    int valuecount[8] = {0} ;
    for( int i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
    {
        valuecount[popcount(i)]++ ;    
    }

    printf( "popcount\tvalues\n") ;
    for( int p = 0; p < 9; p++ )
    {
        printf( "   %d\t\t  %d\n", p, valuecount[p] ) ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
popcount        values 
   0              1
   1              8
   2              28
   3              56
   4              70
   5              56
   6              28
   7              8
   8              1
```

The optimum population count for any word length `n` is always `n / 2`.  For 16-bits the number of values with 8 1-bits is 12870.

Comment: I was not asking how to find the popcount, but rather if there was a different set of byte values (where not all values would have the same popcount), that satisfies the property that no value in the set can be changed to a different value in the set by only clearing bits. Apparently that is not possible.

Comment: @spiff42 perhaps then the question requires clarification.  I see what you mean from your comment.